# Div doesn't appear on hover

Tags: html, css

the div doesn't appear when I hover on a button, but I've used the specified code in w3schools.com. What's wrong?

Here's my code:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(84, 148, 251, 0.8);
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
}

#calltoaction {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  color: black;
  border: rgb(239, 102, 84) solid 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#calltoaction:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  border: black solid 2px
}

.welcome {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
}

#aloha {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.myparallax {
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a26f15fb1ffb6e7c318f710/1516126345399-VIK735PVAIS4BCH4COUE/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFmfxoboNKufWj-55Bgmc-J7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0iXS6XmVv7bUJ418E8Yoc1hjuviiiZmrL38w1ymUdqq4JaGeFUxjM-HeS7Oc-SSFcg/MalindaKathleenReese.jpg?format=1500w');
  height: 100px;
}

.why-you-join {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#what-dyaget {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -21px;
  height: 600px;
}

.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.price .header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.button {
  border: rgb(239, 102, 84) solid 2px;
  background-color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
}

.row {
  height: 520px;
}

.myparallax-2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/malinda/images/f/f3/TranslatorFails.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/350?cb=20190920184709');
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

#faq {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.question-column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.question-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#q {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#a {
  text-align: justify;
}

#trialrequest,
#trialrequest-2 {
  border: none
}

#trialrequest:hover {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px #5494fb;
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

#trialrequest-3 {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: none;
  }
  #what-dyaget {
    height: 2100px;
  }
  .row {
    height: 1440px;
  }
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .question-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .myparallax-2 {
    margin-top: 80px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .myparallax-2 {
    margin-top: 80px !important;
  }
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  #trialrequest-2 {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #trialrequest-3:hover {
    background-color: rgba(249, 112, 110);
    color: white;
    border: solid 2px rgba(249, 112, 110)
  }
}

#moreinfo {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#moreinfo:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important
}

q {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#trialrequest-2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#trialrequest-2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(249, 112, 110);
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 19.5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.dropdown ul a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown ul li {
  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25)
}

.myDIV:hover .hide {
  display: initial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>MALINDA community</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a><button id="calltoaction">Join / Log In</button></a>
    <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#what-dyaget">Pricing</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Login</a></li>
      <li><a>Join</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As I've said before, this dropdown is made as said in the w3schools.com site.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript part that's missing or is this CSS only? You've included jQuery but I don't see it being used.

Comment: @j08691 It's css only.

Comment: You don't have any styles on `.dropdown` (or a child of that class) to show any items. What is your intended behavior? It looks like you have `.myDIV:hover .hide` in your CSS, but in your HTML you don't have any class `myDIV`.

Comment: Can you link to the w3schools example?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_display_element_hover.asp

Comment: So, what shall I do?

Comment: `#calltoaction:hover + .dropdown { display: block; } `

Comment: Ok, I'm really sorry... but it's for a virtual school project I have to turn in in a week (I'm in the southern hemisphere and It's winter)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp is probably more relevant to your use rather than the link you posted. Try this out instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you adjust your HTML to place the hidden dropdown directly after the nav item you want it to interact with, then you can add the CSS rule:

```
/* show the dropdown when hovering on the nav item */
.navbar a:hover + .dropdown, 
/* show the dropdown when hovering on the hidden items */ 
.dropdown:hover {
  display: initial;
}
```

to display the hidden dropdown when you hover over the nav item.

*Note that this currently doesn't have keyboard/accessibility support, this is just a slightly modified version of the code you're currently working with that does work correctly with a mouse.*

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(84, 148, 251, 0.8);
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
}

#calltoaction {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  color: black;
  border: rgb(239, 102, 84) solid 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#calltoaction:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  border: black solid 2px
}

.welcome {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
}

#aloha {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.myparallax {
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5a26f15fb1ffb6e7c318f710/1516126345399-VIK735PVAIS4BCH4COUE/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFmfxoboNKufWj-55Bgmc-J7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0iXS6XmVv7bUJ418E8Yoc1hjuviiiZmrL38w1ymUdqq4JaGeFUxjM-HeS7Oc-SSFcg/MalindaKathleenReese.jpg?format=1500w');
  height: 100px;
}

.why-you-join {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

#what-dyaget {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -21px;
  height: 600px;
}

.columns {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.price {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.price:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.price .header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price .grey {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.button {
  border: rgb(239, 102, 84) solid 2px;
  background-color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgb(239, 102, 84);
}

.row {
  height: 520px;
}

.myparallax-2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/malinda/images/f/f3/TranslatorFails.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/350?cb=20190920184709');
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

#faq {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.question-column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.question-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#q {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#a {
  text-align: justify;
}

#trialrequest,
#trialrequest-2 {
  border: none
}

#trialrequest:hover {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px #5494fb;
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

#trialrequest-3 {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: none;
  }
  #what-dyaget {
    height: 2100px;
  }
  .row {
    height: 1440px;
  }
  .columns {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .question-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .myparallax-2 {
    margin-top: 80px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .myparallax-2 {
    margin-top: 80px !important;
  }
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  #trialrequest-2 {
    border-radius: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #trialrequest-3 {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #trialrequest-3:hover {
    background-color: rgba(249, 112, 110);
    color: white;
    border: solid 2px rgba(249, 112, 110)
  }
}

#moreinfo {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#moreinfo:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important
}

q {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#trialrequest-2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#trialrequest-2:hover {
  background-color: rgba(249, 112, 110);
  color: white;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 19.5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.dropdown ul a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.dropdown ul li {
  padding-top: 5px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25)
}

.myDIV:hover .hide {
  display: initial;
  color: red;
}

.navbar a:hover+.dropdown,
.dropdown:hover {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>MALINDA community</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a><button id="calltoaction">Join / Log In</button></a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li><a>Login</a></li>
        <li><a>Join</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#what-dyaget">Pricing</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh that's true but now it gets stuck on the navbar and I can't see it :-*

Comment: Yup. I'm talking bout your example. I put the "dropdown" div on the "navbar" div. If you run the snippet, you'll see you can't see the "Join" and "Login" links, just a little black bar.

Comment: So, based on my answer before, what shall I do to make the dropdown display neatly and fully visible?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't imagine that's the issue, but using Chrome for me appears to work as intended; I can see both the "Login" and "Join" links when hovering over the "Join / Log in" nav item.

Comment: I'm using Safari

Comment: Updated - I removed the `overflow: hidden;` rule for the `.navbar` selector and now it should work.

Comment: This is just a functional working example of what you were trying to do (using your existing CSS styles). Feel free to adjust the rest of the CSS as needed to make it look how you want.